# Рефактор метода onCreateView

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть фрагмент, в котором метод `onCreateVew`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();
    return view;
}
```

Хочу вынести реализацию `recyclerView` отдельно в дополнительный метод и просто объявить его в `onCreateView`:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    initViews();
    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();
    return view;
}

private initViews() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

}
```

но ругается на `view.findViewById`. Мол надо объявить. Подскажите как лучше сделать.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Где и на что ругается? Что не получается? Покажите попытку выноса кода в отдельный метод

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к необъявленной переменной. Переменная, объявленная в к-л методе не видна за пределами этого метода. Выхода 2

1. Неправильный в данном случае - вынести переменную `View view` на уровень класса. Так она будет доступна во всех методах и внутренних классах класса. В данном случчае это не нужно и принесёт больше проблем, чем пользы.
2. Правильный способ - передать `View view` из метода onCreateView в метод initViews через аргументы последнего так:

```
private initViews(View view) {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}
```

Вызывать теперь метод так:

```
initViews(view);
```